# customize error message for nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

when deleting an entity in nhibernate i get an exception with this error message:
delete statement conflicted with column reference constraint ..etc
of course the exception is wrapped in long series of exceptions.

the error message is normal, but can i make nhibernate shows more polite error message to the user ??
in another words:
is there any conventions which with, i can customize the exception ??

I'm using Oracle 11g data base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can implement `ISQLExceptionConverter` to customize the exceptions thrown by NHibernate.

[Here's](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/06/improving-ado-exception-management-in.html) a complete example.